# Launching ROS on QNX 7.0

Tags: ros, roscore, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have compiled ROS from source for QNX and ported the binaries to the QNX machine. As a first step Id have to source the setup script in the devel folder. Since "source" command does not work in QNX, I had to run it as an executable. It uses ksh and so I replaced bash with ksh in setup.bash and tried to run it. While trying to run the _setup_tools.py from the setup.sh, python throws me the following error

ImportError: No module named site
Failed to run '"/opt/qnx/install/arm_catkin_ros/devel_isolated/topic_tools/_setup_util.py" ': return code 1

It seems that python is looking for the dist-packages folder which is not available on my QNX machine. Any pointers or ideas on how I have to modifiy my script or get over this. I need to just test roscore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264906/launching-ros-on-qnx-7.0/) by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path was not set to site-packages on my QNX machine. That fixed the issue

---

Originally posted by [mhariharasudan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3407/mhariharasudan/) with karma: 70 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0